# Ubuntu 16.04 USB - UEFI Installation - Will Not Boot on BIOS Machine

Tags: ubuntu, osx, grub2, uefi, disk-encryption

My ultimate aim is the following:
- A portable installation of ubuntu 16.04 LTS that will run on BIOS and EFI and UEFI machines
- An encrypted disk (not just home folder)

I have the following machines:
- Mid 2015 Macbook Pro
- 2007 PC - BIOS motherboard, core2 quad processor, 8GB DDR2 RAM - running windows 10

So far I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a 64GB usb key with the following partitions:
- 300MB EFI partition
- 300MB Boot Partition (ext2)
- 63.4GB (or whatever) encrypted partition (ext4)
- boot loader installed to the USB device (not a partition)

this configuration allows the USB to boot on the macbook pro, but on the windows machine I get the following:

```
error: unknown filesystem
```

I saw on this page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Multiboot_pendrives) that a "multiboot pendrive" is discussed, however this page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS) suggests that it is unstable.

Is it possible to install ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a USB such that it is encrypted, and that it can boot on EFI and BIOS machines?

Thank you,

Edit: all computers are 64bit